# Which is better option when viewing video on mobile (lesson recording) - automatic vs manual video retry

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, video

When viewing video recordings in a mobile app, if the video stops playing due to different reasons like, internet failure, server issue, etc., what would be the best way to retry playing the video -

1. Manually - allowing the user to click on a 'Tap to retry' option?
2. Auto - automatically retry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Both.**

Allow the user to manually retry but as soon as the video buffered enough to display a decent amount of the video the app should automatically start playing the video.

I have no sources for this claim, just seems like common sense to me.